# Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with JavaScript. I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Javascript:

```
var vidCounter = 0;
vidCounter++;

var originalDiv;
var newVideo = document.createElement("video");

newVideo.setAttribute("name", vidCounter);
newVideo.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
originalDiv = document.getElementById("othersarea");
document.body.insertBefore(newVideo, originalDiv);
```

It is trying to add a `<video>` tag below a div called `othersarea`.

```
<div id="remoteVideos">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Others</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="othersarea"></div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

I also want to run `attachMediaStream([VIDEO TAG HERE HOW?], event.stream);` on my new video tag.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to call `insertBefore` on the parent element of the element you're inserting before. `document.body` is not the parent, it's far up in the DOM hierarchy.

And to insert after a DIV, you have to insert before its next sibling.

```
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("remoteVideos");
parentDiv.insertBefore(newVideo, originalDiv.nextSibling);
```

See the examples in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Now I get this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined `

Comment: That means `getElementById` can't find the ID. Make sure the code is run after the DOM is loaded, e.g. it should be in an event handler or `window.onload`.

Answer (score 37):

Try using the *parentNode*:

```
originalDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(newVideo, originalDiv);
```

This will insert newVideo directly in front of the originalDiv.

The reason is that `node.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode)` uses `node` as a reference to the element that surrounds the `existingNode`.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

It's also what Google Analytics does:
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/11/appendchild-vs-insertbefore/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be sure which element is your parent element.

In your case, you have an HTML code like this

```
<div id="remoteVideos">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Others</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="othersarea">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `<div id="remoteVideos"></div>` is your parent element, under this elemnt your have few more elments such as `<div class="title"></div>` and
`<div id="othersarea"></div>` which are child of `<div id="remoteVideos"></div>` element. Aditionally, you have `<h2>Others</h2>` elemnt which is child of `<div class="title"></div>` element and now `<div class="title"></div>` is parent element to `<h2>Others</h2>`. Once you understand which is child element and which one is parent element you will never get this error.

Now you can simply select the parent element specifically.

```
const remoteParentElement = document.getElementById('remoteVideos');
const originalDiv = document.getElementById("othersarea");
remoteParentElement.insertBefore(newVideo, originalDiv);
```

Or you can also get the parent element with the [parent node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

```
const originalDiv = document.getElementById("othersarea");
originalDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(newVideo, originalDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to turn off some Google Chrome Plugins and reload your window (they sometimes affect DOM)

Comment: welcome to SO - this answer is generic in nature, and it's not clear to me how it pertains to the specific technology mentioned in the question; you could definitely improve this answer by explaining to readers why your solution works in more detail