# False "the node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."

Tags: javascript, dom

None of the other related questions had a working answer, thus I decided to ask here myself.

While writing JavaScript I keep getting the following error no matter what I try:

> Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

This is the line of code I have, after replacing variable names:

```js
newElement.insertBefore(document.body, aChildOfDocumentBody);
```

Both `newElement` and `aChildOfDocumentBody` are defined with `getElementById`.

**Even when I try** `newElement.insertBefore(document.body, document.body.children[0])` **JavaScript says that the child doesn't belong to `document.body`. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: No, it says that `aChildOfDocumentBody` is not a child of `newElement`

Comment: Duplicate of [Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23401641/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be just a misordering of variables in your function call

```
newElement.insertBefore(document.body, document.body.children[0])
```

Should (I think) be

```
document.body.insertBefore(newElement, document.body.children[0]);
```

Comment: Just found it out myself, thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution and am writing this here for others:

**You need to use `.insertBefore` on the parent!**

So I was supposed to do `document.body.insertBefore(newElement, ...)`

If only this method had a docstring...

Comment: "*If only this method had a docstring*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: @Bergi it seems typescript was decieving me with different parameter names and literally no docstring, will make sure to check mozilla from now on!